# 'Cannot use object of type stdClass as array' using Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, tags

I am trying to retrieve the slug for a tag inside a wordpress post, now its possible to get all tag info using

```
$tag = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
```

More info on this on the [Wordpress Docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags)

By using this you should get data returned like this...

```
Array
(
   [0] => stdClass Object
       (
           [term_id] => 4
           [name] => tag2
           [slug] => tag2
           [term_group] => 0
           [term_taxonomy_id] => 4
           [taxonomy] => post_tag
           [description] => 
           [parent] => 0
           [count] => 7
       )

   [1] => stdClass Object
       (
           [term_id] => 7
           [name] => tag5
           [slug] => tag5
           [term_group] => 0
           [term_taxonomy_id] => 7
           [taxonomy] => post_tag
           [description] => 
           [parent] => 0
           [count] => 6
       )

)
```

Now what I want is the slug for the first item which should be as follows

```
$tag[0]['slug']
```

However by doing so I recieve this php error:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as
>   array

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? and whats the best way to get the slug data

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Note that the array contains *objects* (instances of `stdClass`), not other arrays. So the syntax is:

```
$tag[0]->slug
```

Comment: Ah, thats exactly what I was looking for. Think I need to go back to php basics

Comment: Hi, instead of 'slug', I have '@classId' as the name to be fetched. Getting syntax error at token '@', do you know any work around? Thanks

Comment: fyi. I am calling a mysql proc with out parameter, and then doing a select in next query.

Comment: @mtk, use `$tag[0]->{"@classId"}`.

Comment: @radu that didn't work. Have asked the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693234/php-mysql-get-value-of-out-parameter-from-a-stored-proc). Please see.

Answer (score 3):

Another option should be to explicitly cast $tag[0] into an array:

```
$t = (array)$tag[0];
$t["slug"] = ...
```

Can't get it to work though

Comment: I created a custom walker for my menu in wordpress. Somehow it used both: **objects** and **arrays** in one argument. This little peace of code did the trick, didn't know about it.