# PHP -  MySQL gets value of out parameter from a stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, out-parameters

I have called a MySQL stored procedure from PHP using `mysqli`. This has one out parameter.

```
$rs = $mysqli->query("CALL addNewUser($name,$age,@id)");
```

Here, @id is the out parameter. Next, I fire the following query to get the value of the out parameter:

```
$rs2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT @id");
while($row = $rs->fetch_object()){
    echo var_dump($row);
}
```

The output of `var_dump` is as follows.

```
object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["@id"]=> string(6) "100026" }
```

So, now I want to retrieve the value of `@id`, which I am unable to. I tried `$row[0]->{@id}` but this gave following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or even just do a `"SELECT @id AS id"` then `$row->id` will work fine.  I always rename select columns to keep the name meaningful when necessary :-)

BTW, you can simply concatenate the call and select @... (with a ; statement delimiter) and the RS will be the returned value.  Unfortunately this returns a mutli-resultset and you need to flush the full set otherwise the subsequent queries will stall.  See following examples:

```
$db->multi_query( "CALL addNewUser($name,$age,@id);SELECT @id as id" );
$db->next_result();            // flush the null RS from the call
$rs=$db->store_result();       // get the RS containing the id
echo $rs->fetch_object()->id, "\n";
$rs->free();
```

Alternatively add the select into the addNewUser and return a RS instead of out param

```
$rs = $db->query( "CALL addNewUser($name,$age)" );
echo $rs->fetch_object()->id, "\n";
$rs->close();
$db->next_result();            // flush the null RS from the call
```

The first returns a multiquery (NULL, RS) set and the second a (RS, NULL) set, hence you can use a simple query() call which embeds the first fetch_object(), but you still need to flush the RS stack.

Comment: Hey, Can you please elaborate on the 2nd suggestion you gave. Thanks :)

Comment: @mtk, Sorry, I should check BTWs against my code :-(  I used the second version.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the explanation. All examples work well. Was looking for just one solution but got three :)

Answer (score 4):

Just `$row->{"@id"}` would work here. You can't use an `stdClass` as an array (`$row[0]...`).

Comment: You need to quote the column name, in order to avoid notices and such. `@id` becomes `'id'` (unless you have a defined constant named `id`).

Comment: @cHao .@MadaraUchiha  @ exapmle@abc.com

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can just fetch the data as an array using `mysqli::fetch_assoc()` and access the data using `$row['@id']`.

Answer (score 3):

Another correct methods its working fine: Cheers!!

```
$procedureName = 'VALIDATE_USER';
$procedure = "CALL $procedureName('$username','$pwd',@p_userid)";
$results1 = $dbconnection->query($procedure);
$results2 = $dbconnection->query("SELECT @p_userid");
$num_rows = $results2->num_rows;
if ($num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $results2->fetch_object())
    {
    echo $row->{"@p_userid"};

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution:

```
enter code $res = $conn->multi_query( "CALL PROCNAME(@x);SELECT @x" );
if( $res ) {
  $results = 0;
  do {
    if ($result = $conn->store_result()) {
      printf( "<b>Result #%u</b>:<br/>", ++$results );
      while( $row = $result->fetch_row() ) {
        foreach( $row as $cell ) echo $cell, "&nbsp;";
      }
      $result->close();
      if( $conn->more_results() ) echo "<br/>";
    }
  } while( $conn->next_result() );
}
$conn->close();
```