# how to access MySQL OUT variable through PHP mysqli without result set

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is it possible to access an `OUT` variable from an SP called through mysqli without returning it via `SELECT` one way or another? I had a good look and tried the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693234/php-mysql-gets-value-of-out-parameter-from-a-stored-procedure) but it always needs a result set called within or after the SP to work.

Consider this code:

SQL:

```
DELIMITER $

# DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS outVar$

CREATE PROCEDURE outVar(OUT myVar TINYINT(1))
BEGIN

    SET myVar = 1;

END$

DELIMITER ;

CALL outVar(@myVar);

SELECT @myVar;
```

PHP:

```
 <?php

    $Conn = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "123456789", "test");

    $RResult = $Conn->query("CALL outVar(@myVar);");

    print_r($RResult->fetch_assoc());
?>
```

This returns the following:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpTest.php on line 7
```

Because there are no results returned in tabular form, fair enough. So am I correct in assuming that while `OUT` is elegant within mysql it's of no use in the mysqli context without the help of a result set leaving `OUT` redundant in this context? If not I'd love to know how to do it.

Thanks,

James

Comment: did you try SP page in mysqli manual?

Comment: I have now. `P()` in all cases either has no result, creates a result set using `SELECT` or the `OUT` is recovered using a subsequent `SELECT` and session variable. Is there an example where the procedure has an `OUT`, but no `SELECT` to create a result set and this value is available in PHP as it would be within MySQL?

Comment: I have an impression that the manual page is rather clear stating that mysqli does not have any support for out/inout variables whatsoever

Comment: To add insult to injury, even PDO_Mysql doesn't, though for other drivers it's supported

Comment: "The values of INOUT/OUT parameters are accessed using session variables." Well spotted, apologies for taking the long way round and thanks for the pointers. Good to know what's right.