# error while loading wordpress post using ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to retrieve the content of a wordpress post using its ID:

```
$loadpost = url_to_postid($actual_link); 
$newpost = get_post($loadpost);
echo '<article id="post-'.$newpost["ID"].'"><h1>'.$newpost["post_title"].'</h1>'.$newpost["post_content"];
```

$loadpost returns a valid ID but somehow this expression does not work.
IE returns:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /hermes/waloraweb046/b428/moo.snippetspacecom/splittemplate/wp-content/themes/split/index.php on line 24
```

What does this mean?

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171699/cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array-using-wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because get_post(); by default [outputs as an OBJECT](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post)

What you want to return is

```
echo '<article id="post-'.$newpost->ID.'"><h1>'.$newpost->post_title.'</h1>'.$newpost->post_content;
```

Comment: same answer as xlordt but more complete. Thanks, it works great :).

Answer (score 1):

change all [''] to -> example

```
$newpost->ID;
$newpost->post_title
```

wp passes most parameters as objects and not as arrays.

Answer (score 1):

By default [`get_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) returns an object, pass `ARRAY_A` as a second parameter for it to return an associative array.

```
$loadpost = url_to_postid($actual_link); 
$newpost = get_post($loadpost, ARRAY_A);
echo '<article id="post-'.$newpost["ID"].'"><h1>'.$newpost["post_title"].'</h1>'.$newpost["post_content"];
```

Comment: @SnippetSpace did you call `get_post` with `ARRAY_A` as a second parameter or just copied my code?, if the latter there was a mistake in my code if is corrected now.